# In JQ is there a better way to process an array using a sliding window than using indexes?

Tags: json, jq

In my specific case, I'm looking to convert input like `["a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3]` into an object like `{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}`, but the general technique is processing an array using a sliding window (in this case, of size 2).

I can make this work using indexes, but it's rather ugly, and it suffers from having to load the entire array into memory, so it's not great for streaming:

```bash
# Just creates input to play with, in this case, all the letters from 'a' to 'z'
function input () {
  printf '"%s" ' {a..z} | jq --slurp --compact-output '.'
}

input | 
  jq '. as $i | $i 
    | keys 
    | map(select (. % 2 == 0)) 
    | map({key:($i[.]|tostring), value:$i[. + 1]}) 
    | from_entries'
```

In a perfect world, this could look something like this:

```bash
input | 
  jq 'sliding(2;2) 
    | map({key: (.[0]|tostring), value: .[1]) 
    | from_entries'
```

I don't see anything like that in the docs, but I'd like to know if there's any techniques that could get me to a cleaner solution.

##### Tangent on `sliding`

I used `sliding(2;2)` a placeholder for "something that does this in one go", but for the curious, the semantics come from Scala's `sliding(size: Int, step: Int)` collection method.

Because `jq` returns `null` if you're out of range, the `size` would be mostly to make life easier when you're looking at an intermediate result. Borrowing the `while` implementation from @pmf's answer, the second has a much easier to understand intermediate output when the `size` argument is applied:

```bash
$ input | jq --compact-output 'while(. != []; .[2:])'
["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
["c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
["e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
["g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
["i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
["k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
["m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
["o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
["q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
["s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
["u","v","w","x","y","z"]
["w","x","y","z"]
["y","z"]
$ input | jq --compact-output 'while(. != []; .[2:])[:3]'
["a","b","c"]
["c","d","e"]
["e","f","g"]
["g","h","i"]
["i","j","k"]
["k","l","m"]
["m","n","o"]
["o","p","q"]
["q","r","s"]
["s","t","u"]
["u","v","w"]
["w","x","y"]
["y","z"]
```

Comment: What do `2` and `2` refer to in `sliding(2;2)`?

Comment: @pmf: size and step. So `2;2` would be process adjacent elements, `2;3` would be take 2, skip 1, `3;2` would be a sliding window of size 3 with an overlap of 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am confused with the meaning of `2` and `2` in `sliding(2;2)`, but here's a definition for `sliding` that can master what (I think) you are looking for (with maybe different parameter values). It generates an array of arrays using a step size and a length parameter:

```bash
def sliding($a;$b): [while(. != []; .[$a:])[:$b]];
```

Examples:

```bash
sliding(2;2) | map({key: (.[0]|tostring), value: .[1]}) | from_entries
```

```json
{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f","g":"h","i":"j","k":"l","m":"n","o":"p","q":"r","s":"t","u":"v","w":"x","y":"z"}
```

Skipping:

```bash
sliding(3;2) | map({key: (.[0]|tostring), value: .[1]}) | from_entries
```

```json
{"a":"b","d":"e","g":"h","j":"k","m":"n","p":"q","s":"t","v":"w","y":"z"}
```

Overlapping:

```bash
sliding(1;2) | map({key: (.[0]|tostring), value: .[1]}) | from_entries
```

```json
{"a":"b","b":"c","c":"d","d":"e","e":"f","f":"g","g":"h","h":"i","i":"j","j":"k","k":"l","l":"m","m":"n","n":"o","o":"p","p":"q","q":"r","r":"s","s":"t","t":"u","u":"v","v":"w","w":"x","x":"y","y":"z","z":null}
```

Note: the second parameter is not really used, as you always take two  items from the current window, so you could actually omit it entirely, or hard-code it to `2`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reduce` to go through the array, and take two items at a time:

```bash
jq 'reduce while(. != []; .[2:]) as [$key, $val] ({}; .[$key] = $val)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's what [`_nwise`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/cff5336ec71b6fee396a95bb0e4bea365e0cd1e8/src/builtin.jq#L102) is for.

```
reduce _nwise(2) as [$k, $v] ({}; .[$k] = $v)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/fCpTEhJWsVO)</sup>

Comment: Great find! Is this documented anywhere other than the source?

Comment: I'd love to accept this answer, as it's got exactly the semantics I'm looking for, but it looks like this is not part of the public and stable API, so it's more vulnerable to becoming outdated without notice.